# How to fill web forms in python without using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Is there any module or way in python for filling web form without using selenium
[image]

Comment: Is that [google forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/)?

Comment: any type of web forms @heitor

Comment: without selenium @DaveIdito

Comment: Any specific reasons why you are avoiding Selenium?

Comment: because I need to do this process without opening any browser or selenium driver @DaveIdito

Comment: Well, there's lots of ways to do it, depending on the website you could use an API (take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073971/http-post-to-a-google-form/47444396) for google forms). Or just use the network inspector tool to find out what requests your browser is making and try to mimic them using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for example. But Selenium is a pretty versatile solution since many websites have anti-automation measures and don't work well with plain requests without user-agents.

Comment: If the GUI is the problem, take a look at headless mode on [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python) or [chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver) @dx4iot

Comment: @dx4iot any headless browser should do the job then. Here's a [list](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers). The processes would remain the same nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple reasons, logging into sites like Gmail and Facebook using WebDriver is not recommended. Aside from being against the usage terms for these sites (where you risk having the account shut down), it is slow and unreliable.

The ideal practice is to use the APIs that email providers offer, or in the case of Facebook the developer tools service which exposes an API for creating test accounts, friends and so forth. Although using an API might seem like a bit of extra hard work, you will be paid back in speed, reliability, and stability. The API is also unlikely to change, whereas webpages and HTML locators change often and require you to update your test framework.

Logging in to third party sites using WebDriver at any point of your test increases the risk of your test failing because it makes your test longer. A general rule of thumb is that longer tests are more fragile and unreliable.